# ios facebook app sharing session with safari

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

Hey guyz m new at iphone can someone please elaborate why my facebook app is sharing session with safari browser when i log out using

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

is does not close my session and if the user log in again after logging out the app shares session with safari and when i clear session of safari my app asks for credentials